# Plugin frontend page design irrespective of the theme used

Tags: plugin-development, pages, front-end, design

I am writing a WordPress plugin which will have some front-end pages including inputs, forms, buttons etc. The plugin should be usable with different themes.

But I am confused or don't know how to design the frontend pages since I don't know which CSS styles/classes can be used. And if I use my custom CSS styles that may look awkward with the current theme.

What is the best practice in this case?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Can you edit your question so it's more specific? Currently it's more of a discussion starter which doesn't lend itself well. You need to be able to mark an answer as the canonical answer, asked in a way that someone can factually answer it. This isn't a discussion/support forum.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know which CSS styles/classes can be used.

You can't know this, not without knowing which plugins and themes there are installed. Prefix your classes so they're unique and it becomes a non-issue.

> And if I use my custom CSS styles that may look awkward with the current theme.

Someone somewhere can write a theme that will look awkward. This isn't a WordPress problem but one of CSS specificity.